# JPA ORM are relations efficient?

Tags: java, jpa, orm

I have some doubts on that how for instance `@OneToMany` might be efficient. Let's assume object A have collections of B objects inside of it and that collection have 100k objects

```
class A {
    List<B> b; //.size() == 100.000
    ...
}
```

Even I mark b to being fetch LAZY what would following pseudo-code do?

```
select from database object into A a;
a.b.add(new B());
```

If I'm correct, because I made an access to field it has to be loaded, yes? So just to make one insert I have downloaded 100k rows from DB?

Can anyone clarify my doubts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right: all 100k rows will be loaded.

What to do?

I suppose that there is also a reverse relationship from B to A. In this case, to avoid the performance problem you persist the B instance, when A has his list of B not loaded. Alternatively you could make a native query.